# IE8 failing to .append() jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I wrote this function to make columns sortable. I want to rearrange divs based that are associated on a particular order number. It works fine in chrome and firefox, but for some reason in IE8 instead of, at the end of the function, appending all the rearranged content to a the `#current_orders_content2` div, all of the content simply disappears. The function checks out in JSlint (via jsfiddle) and what's curious is that looking at all the values at the end (via IE console), everything looks all right—values are what I would expect them to be. It just seem that the `append()` fails. So I tested with `.html()`, `appendTo` and still no joy. It works if I pass it an html string, but is failing with these jquery objects.

Any ideas on why or how i can make it work?

Thanks!

```
$('.sortable').click(function () {
    "use strict";
    if ($(this).hasClass('sortable_numeric')) {

        /*
        *function sets ascending/descending classes
        *for formatting, placement of arrow_up.png, arrow_down.png
        *returns the sort order to be used below "asc" or "desc"
        */
        var sort_order = sort_class_distribution($(this));
        var current_val = "";
        var order_number = "";

        /*
        *determine what column is being sorted
        *remove the "_header" text from the id to
        *get this information
        */
        var sort_column = this.id;

        sort_column = sort_column.replace("header_", "");

        /*
        *append "_div" to the end of the string to get
        *the class of the divs we are sorting by
        */
        sort_column += "_div";

        var valuesArr = [];

        $('.' + sort_column).each(function () {

            var current_val = $.trim($(this).text());

            current_val = parseInt(current_val, 10);

            valuesArr.push(current_val);

        });


        var sorted = [];

        if (sort_order == "asc") {

            sorted = valuesArr.slice(0).sort(sortA);


        } else if (sort_order == "desc") {

            sorted = valuesArr.slice(0).sort(sortD);

        }

        /*
        * for each item in this array, get the parent div 
        * with the class order_and_lines_container_div. 
        * 
        * push it into an array of its own to to put back 
        * onto the page in the order of the sorted array
        */

        var containerArr = [];
        var current_container = "";
        var c = 0;

        for ( c = 0; c <= sorted.length; c++ ) {

            current_container = $('#order_container_' + sorted[c]);

            containerArr.push(current_container);

        }

        $('#currentOrdersContent2').html('');

        for ( c = 0; c <= sorted.length; c++ ) {

            $('#currentOrdersContent2').append(containerArr[c]);

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Do you have a DOCTYPE set in your HTML?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: try with just <!DOCTYPE html> otherwise can we see the whole HTML? It could be due to a broken HTML.

Comment: nah, didn't work.. and html is definitely not broken i don't think. i mean, it renders fine when the page loads..

Comment: with broken HTML I mean that it might have a non-closed tag or things like that, which other browsers do fix for you but IE8 doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the issue or not, but your loops are going out of bounds.

This...

```
for ( c = 0; c <= sorted.length; c++ ) {
```

should be this...

```
 // -----------v---constrain to indices less than sorted.length
for ( c = 0; c < sorted.length; c++ ) {
```

Also, you seem to be using a lot more code than needed for this sort.

---

Here's your code reworked a bit...

```
$('.sortable').click(function () {
    "use strict";
    if ($(this).hasClass('sortable_numeric')) {

        var sort_order = sort_class_distribution($(this)),
            sort_column = this.id.replace("header_", "") + "_div",
            content2 = $('#currentOrdersContent2');

        var sorted = $('.' + sort_column).map(function () {
                return parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
            })
            .toArray()
            .sort(sort_order == "asc" ? sortA : sortD);

        $.each(sorted, function(i, item) {
            content2.append($('#order_container_' + item));
        });
    }
});
```

Some of the changes are...

- removed a bunch of unnecessary variable declarations *(either shadowed or unused)*
- Used `.map()`. This simply iterates the elements, and puts whatever you provide as a `return` value in a new jQuery object, so you end up with a jQuery object full of numbers.
- Got rid of `$.trim()` since `parseInt` ignores leading/trailing whitespace
- Used `.toArray()` to convert the new jQuery object to an actual Array.
- Called `.sort()` immediately and assign the return value to the variable, since it returns the same Array, though modified.
- At that point, simply did the `.append()` of each item. When appending, the element is removed from its original location, and placed in the new location, so there's no need to cache and clear the elements.

The `.map().toArray().sort()` is just method chaining. `.map()` returns the new jQuery object as noted above. `.toArray()` is called on that object, and returns an Array. `.sort()` is called on that Array, and returns the same Array, which is assigned to the variable.

This part `sort_order == "asc" ? sortA : sortD` is a conditional operator, which is like a shorthand for an `if...else`. Basically, if the condition is true, return `sortA`, else return `sortD`.

Comment: @thomas: You mean about the "more code than needed"? First thing I see is that there shouldn't be any need for two loops at the end. Why not do it in one with `$('#currentOrdersContent2').append($('#order_container_' + sorted[c]));`.

Comment: @thomas: I'm working on an extreme code reduction `;)`. It'll be untested, and if you don't like such dense code, you can unroll (or ignore) the changes. I'll notify you in a few minutes. In the meantime, did the loop constraint help the issue?

Comment: that's great! i'd love to see how it's done more professionally. the only thing about splitting them up, is that the first loop plucks out the divs in sequence, then the main container div (`#currentOrders2`) is cleared, then the newly ordered divs are put back in. so trying to combine them is proving a little difficult. but i'm working on it.

Comment: @thomas: Are they moving from one container to another, or are they being rearranged within the same container?

Comment: rearranged within one container.

Comment: @thomas: Then is there any content being deleted, or is it all being kept and rearranged? In other words, are you wanting to end up with all the same content, just in a different order?

Comment: right. it takes a number out of these divs, re-arranges those numbers to be in ascending or descending order, grabs the parent divs associated with those now-ordered numbers, puts them in a jquery object, deletes the originals, the puts in the ordered ones. sounds really complicated when i say it all like that..

Comment: @thomas: When reordering, there's really no need to delete the elements. DOM elements can only be in one location at a time, so when one is appended somewhere, it's automatically removed from its original spot. Give this *(untested)* code a try. http://jsfiddle.net/dEAe9/ *EDIT: Just updated the link due to a mistake in a last minute change.*

Comment: this part is particularly heavy in voodoo.. `var sorted = $('.' + sort_column).map(function () {
            return parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
        })
            .toArray()
            .sort(sort_order == "asc" ? sortA : sortD);
`can you help me understand a little bit what you did?

Comment: @thomas: Glad it works. Always a little nervous with untested code. I'll post the code in my answer, and give some explanations for the changes.

Comment: in this statement `.sort(sort_order == "asc" ? sortA : sortD);` why do you need to invoke jquery sort. i didn't post it, but they call these functions `function sortA(a,b){ 
  return a - b;
}
function sortD(a,b){ 
  return b - a;
}`

Comment: @thomas: It isn't jQuery sort. Remember that `toArray` converts the jQuery object to an actual Array, so when we chain `.sort()` after `toArray()`, we're calling `.sort()` on the Array, not the jQuery object. Then `sort_order == "asc" ? sortA : sortD` just chooses which sort function to use. If `sort_order` is equal to `"asc"`, then `sortA` is passed, otherwise `sortD` is passed.

Comment: ...it would be the same as if we assigned the result of `toArray()` to the `sorted` variable, then did this... `if (sort_order === "asc") { sorted.sort(sortA); } else { sorted.sort(sortD); }`

Comment: hello, me again. sorry to keep bugging you, but i tried to apply this method to an alphabet style of sorting and it didn't really work. the text that i'm trying to sort is within the div identified by the `var sorted = $('.' + sort_column)` statement, so i tried to include that. offhand, do you see what i've done wrong? thanks `var sorted = $('.' + sort_column).children('div').map(function () {
                return $.trim($(this).text());
        })
            .toArray()
            .sort(sort_order == "asc" ? sorted.sort : sorted.sort.reverse());`

Comment: @thomas: The issue is with the value passed to `.sort()`. If `sort_orger == "asc"` is `true`, you're passing the exact same `.sort()` function *(or actually you're not since `sorted` isn't yet defined)*. If it's `false`, you're... well I'm not sure what you're trying to do. `;)` What you need to do is pass a function that defines the sort order, so you should be passing your `sortA` or `sortD` functions, or something similar. `.sort(sort_order == "asc" ? sortA : sortD);`

Comment: ...or since you're sorting text, you can actually just do `.sort()` with no argument passed. Then if it should descend, you can do `if(sort_order !== "asc") { sorted.reverse(); }`