# associating sorted dates with divs they originated in (before sorting)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collection of parent `div`s that are labeled with  unique order numbers based on their `id`, so like, `<div id='parent_uniqueID'>` . They each have child divs which contain information on the order: order number (same as above), name, and order date (mm / dd / yy).

I am attempting to sort these parent divs based on each of these columns.

Its easy to sort by the order number and rearrange the parent divs. I sort them, then select the parent divs with something like $('#parent_' + order_number);` And I append them to the page. Also simple for alphanumeric; at the end of the alphanumeric string, I append the order, before I sort it. Which is handy because that way if two orders have an identidcal name, the parent divs default to sorting by order number.

I have no idea though how to, once finished sorting by date, distinguish which date belongs to which parent div, so that I can grab the parent divs by the `ids` and rearrange them on the page.

When I was trying to understand sorting numerically, I received [this really nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146962/1252748), which I am trying to adapt to dates:

```
$('.sortable').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('sortable_date')) {

        var sort_order = sort_class_distribution($(this)),
            sort_column = this.id.replace("header_", "") + "_div",
            content2 = $('#currentOrdersContent2'),
            date_holder = "",
            i = 0;



        var sorted = $('.' + sort_column).map(function () {

            date_holder = $.trim($(this).text());
            //get order number from parent div
            //only_numbers function strips out everything but numbers
            cur_order = only_numbers($(this).parents('.order_details_bg_trigger').attr('id'));


            //check that the text is not "Not given" or "Unavailable"
            if (date_holder.indexOf("/")) {
                cur_date = date_holder.split(" / ");
                //change the text string into a proper javascript date
                return new Date(cur_date[2], cur_date[0] - 1, cur_date[1]);
            } else {
                //if it is 'Not given', assign it today's date
                return new Date();
            }
        }).toArray().sort(sort_order = "asc" ? date_sort_asc : date_sort_desc);


        //change javascript date back to mm / dd / yy format
        //weak attempt to match sorted dates with dates contained in table
        $.each(sorted, function (i, item) {

            cur_date = ('0' + (item.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + ' / ' + ('0' + item.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' / ' + item.getFullYear();

        });

    }

});
```

These are the date sort functions:
*source: https://gist.github.com/1772996*

```
function date_sort_asc(date1, date2) {
    if (date1 > date2) return 1;
    if (date1 < date2) return -1;
    return 0;
}

function date_sort_desc(date1, date2) {
    if (date1 > date2) return -1;
    if (date1 < date2) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this, or a new patten are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use the jQuery metadata plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Metadata). Then give your wrapper (parent) div all the values you might sort on (for example, the date, price, whatever). With all metadata contained in the parent div, you will not have to do any figuring to decide which children go with which parent, just reorder your parent divs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to use HTML5 functionality, one thing you could do to simplify the whole process is to embed some of the key data for each of the parent divs inside the divs themselves. Something like this could be done for each of the parent divs:

```
<div id='parent_uniqueID' data-date='somedate' data-orderNo='someorderno'>
```

Afterwards you can collect the data by using for example jquery like this:

```
$("#parent_uniqueID").data("date")
```

and easily find what you need to compare and sort whithout having to find the locations of the data inside the parent divs. Hope this helps you to get closer to a solution!

Comment: thanks. I've looked into this a bit before, and it does seem really useful. I couldn't get confirmation that browsers support it really well however. ><

Comment: No, you would have to commit to HTML5 technology, and I guess that might bring on its own set of problems. But I belive HTML5 is the future :)